# Backbone is undefined

Tags: backbone.js, coffeescript

Any instance of Backbone doesn't work, my console says it's undefined...

As of now it says:
**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'start' of undefined**

Which correlates to this line:

```
Backbone.history.start()
```

This is my code for app.js:

```
app =
  facebookAuth()

class manageView extends Backbone.View
    constructor: ->
        super

    initialize: ->

    template: _.template($('#manage').html())

    render: ->
        $('#page').append(@template())


class AppRouter extends Backbone.Router
    routes:
        "": "manage"

    initialize: ->

    manage: ->
        new manageView()


$(document).ready( ->
  console.log('document ready')
  app.AppRouter = new AppRouter()
  Backbone.history.start()
)
```

And this is how I've included my js files (they all point to the correct path):

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="../js/underscore-min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="../js/backbone-min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="../js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="../js/less-1.3.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="../js/facebook-auth.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="../js/app.js"></script>
```

Can anyone tell me why? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably router wasn't created at that moment. Try next:

```
class AppRouter extends Backbone.Router
 routes:
        "": "manage"

    initialize: ->
        Backbone.history.start()
    manage: ->
        new manageView()


$(document).ready( ->
  console.log('document ready')
  app.AppRouter = new AppRouter()
)
```

Comment: unfortunately not, I now get this error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'AppRouter' of undefined

Comment: It means that "app" (app = facebookAuth()) is undefined. You can create router independent variable, not field of app object.

Comment: Or you could organize callback which triggers when app created.

Comment: ok, I created it as an independent variable like you said and it worked.. cheers!